# convert image from base64 to image and save in database in django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, html

I'm trying export a string base64 that represents an image taken from canvas html5, this is the code in javascript:

```
var canvas1 = $("#canvas1")[0];
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
dataURL1 = canvas1.toDataURL();
```

Whit ajax I sent the image to server:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/regiter_respuesta_agilidad/",
    data:{
        'imagen1': dataURL1,
    }
});
```

In views.py of django I use base64.b64decode to export the string to image:

```
imagen1 = request.POST['imagen1']
image_data = base64.b64decode(imagen1)
imagene = ContentFile(image_data, 'imagen1.png')
answer = Answer(imagen=imagene)
```

In models.py I have:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)
```

The Problem is when the image is saved, the file imagen1.png is corrupted and I can't open it, Can someone help me with this problem?, or is there another way to do this? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to strip the `data:` off the Data URI returned by `canvas.toDataURL();`.

A quick google search found some code designed for parsing data uris in python https://gist.github.com/zacharyvoase/5538178 and another: [dataurl.py](https://code.google.com/p/python-mom/source/browse/mom/net/scheme/dataurl.py?spec=svn6f9d726af747fc547eeafb8b70509c528dd8845d&r=6f9d726af747fc547eeafb8b70509c528dd8845d)

Comment: This worked for me, I had to add `image_data = base64.b64decode(re.search(r'base64,(.*)', request.POST['imagen1']).group(1))` because the first characters of the data url gave an `Incorrect Padding` error.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line:    `image_data = base64.b64decode(imagen1)`

use this line : `image_data = base64.b64decode(imagen1[22:] + b'=' * (-len(imagen1[22:]) % 4))`